# list of class object in python

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class defined like this

```
class a:
   x=Null
   y=[]
```

and I have a list of the object of class a

```
list=[]
```

and I have function which appends the list with class object

```
start(str,price):
     obj=a()
     obj.x=str
     obj.y.append(price)
     list.append(obj)
```

and I'm calling this function many times

```
start("x1",10)
start("y1",20)
start("z1",30)
start("x1",100)
for i in range(0,len(list))
   print(list[i].x)
   print(list[i].y)
```

now the obj.y  in the list also have all the prices appended to it

is there any alternative way to fulfill this requirement.

I want only one x1 to be appended to list no duplicate for the x attribute of the object but it should be appended to earlier x1 objects list only, also only x1's prices to be appended to x1.y.

**actual output**

```
x1
[10,20,30,100]
y1
[10,20,30,100]
z1
[10,20,30,100]
x1
[10,20,30,100]
```

**expected op**

```
x1
[10,100]
y1
[20]
z1
[30]
```

Comment: Give your class an `__init__` and initialise `y` in that.

Comment: The reason for the actual output is that there is a single a.y that you are appending numbers to.

Comment: btw don’t name variables like list and str.

Comment: You'd better use `Dict[str, List[int]]`. Create a dictionary, whose `key` is "str" and `value` is a list of "price". If you complete the dictionary, converting the dictionary to a list of objects is very easy.

Comment: Use dictionary for this purpose unless you want to do some funky overloading stuff with your class later....see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my response in the code below. This is how I'd implement it to achieve your output targets at first glance. For your purposes, I'd advice to go with a dictionary approach rather than storing each key-value inside its own class object (unless you want to do stuff like overloading which was not stated in your query). Hope it helps, cheers!

```
class test:

    master_dict = {} 

    def __init__(self):
        pass 

    def add_data(self,str,price):
        # function / routine to add data to master_dict
        # str is key, price is value 

        # search if str is part of existing keys to avoid duplication of key
        if str in self.master_dict.keys():
            print("Key already exists. Skipping initialization...") # you can comment this out
            self.master_dict[str].append(price) 
        else:
            # lets init with empty list 
            print("Allocating empty list...") # you can comment this out
            self.master_dict[str] = [] # initialize list 'container' here
            self.master_dict[str].append(price) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # only do this once. Don't keep making an instance of the class
    # if its unnecessary 
    a = test() 

    # then add your data using the method 
    a.add_data('x1', 10)
    a.add_data('x1', 100)
    a.add_data('y1', 20)
    a.add_data('z1', 30)

    # lets check
    for key,value in a.master_dict.items():
        print(key,value)
```

You will get output (you can comment out the unnecessary print)

```
Allocating empty list...
Key already exists. Skipping initialization...
Allocating empty list...
Allocating empty list...
x1 [10, 100]
y1 [20]
z1 [30]
```